# Chunking with Python

Tags: python, csv, chunks, chunking

Hi and happy holidays to everyone!

I have to cope with big csv files (around 5GB each) on a simple laptop, so I am learning to read files in chunks (I am a complete noob in this), using python 2.7 in particular. I found this very nice example

```
# chunked file reading
from __future__ import division
import os

def get_chunks(file_size):
    chunk_start = 0
    chunk_size = 0x20000  # 131072 bytes, default max ssl buffer size
    while chunk_start + chunk_size &lt; file_size:
        yield(chunk_start, chunk_size)
        chunk_start += chunk_size

    final_chunk_size = file_size - chunk_start
    yield(chunk_start, final_chunk_size)

def read_file_chunked(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file_:
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

        print('File size: {}'.format(file_size))

        progress = 0

        for chunk_start, chunk_size in get_chunks(file_size):

            file_chunk = file_.read(chunk_size)

            # do something with the chunk, encrypt it, write to another file...

            progress += len(file_chunk)
            print('{0} of {1} bytes read ({2}%)'.format(
                progress, file_size, int(progress / file_size * 100))
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_file_chunked('some-file.gif')
```

(source: https://gist.github.com/richardasaurus/21d4b970a202d2fffa9c)

but something still is not very clear to me. For example, let's say that I write a piece of code and I want to test it on a small fraction of my dataset, just to check if it runs properly. How could I read, let's say, only the first 10% of my csv file and run my code on that chunk without having to store in the memory the rest of the dataset?
I appreciate any hint - even some reading or external reference is good, if related to chunking files with python. Thank you!

Comment: There are a ton of libraries that help deal with CSV chunking (pandas for example), which I really encourage you to look at.

Comment: if you have specific chunk reading with csv,xlsx or such files you should use pandas, the code example you posted is guide to use chunk when you don't have libraries or unable to use with any restriction

Comment: Using the `chunksize` parameter in the `pd.read_csv` function seems to do the job, but it still isn't very clear how I handle the resulting object. How do I keep, for instance, the first two chunks and discard the others? How can I run some code on these two chunks? The documentation isn't really exhaustive about this. What I get by using it is my original file splitted in chunks according to `chunksize`, but it still is all there (I know I am missing the point here).

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the following CSV file:

[image]

If you open this CSV file with Notepad or any simple text editor you can see this:

```
CU-C2376;Airbus A380;50.00;259.00
J2-THZ;Boeing 737;233.00;213.00
SU-XBG;Embraer ERJ-195;356.00;189.00
TI-GGH;Boeing 737;39.00;277.00
HK-6754J;Airbus A380;92.00;93.00
6Y-VBU;Embraer ERJ-195;215.00;340.00
9N-ABU;Embraer ERJ-195;151.00;66.00
YV-HUI;Airbus A380;337.00;77.00
```

If you observe carefully each line corresponds to one row and each value is separated with a ";".

Let's say i want to read only the first three rows, then:

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
     lines = list()
     for i in range(3):
          lines.append(f.readline())
     #Do some stuff with the first three lines
```

This is a better way of reading chunk of file because let's the file is 10MB and if you read first 3MB the last byte you read may not represent anything.

Alternatively you can use libraries like panda..

Comment: It is quite possible to have a multi-line text field in quotes; you cannot safely assume that each record is only one line (unless your data independently guarantees this).

Comment: @HughBothwell each row is one line...No CSV file has more than a line per row....CSV stands for comma separated values..and each line is called a data record... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values go through this link for poof...

Comment: yes, they say that, and yes, it is *usually* true - but it is not actually guaranteed. See https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/97147-parsing-csv-files-with-multi-line-fields/  It is quite legal to have a multiline field enclosed in quotes. See your own link, second paragraph, "the field may also contain ... embedded line-breaks."